# Android activities.

Tags: android

I am developing an app which has a list view of items. Once a user clicks on an item, it takes him/her to the details page of the item. If I have, say, 10 items in the list view, do I need ten activities for the details of each item, or can I just have one activity to represent the details? 
If I need only one activity, please describe how I can customize details for each list view item yet I have only one activity

Comment: need only one activity

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You are getting downvotes as your question is covered in Android tutorials. Also asking for tutorials is considered off-topic. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: I think you are really new to Android development. I suggest you take some of the Android development courses on Udacity.com. Start with this one [Android Development for Beginners](https://in.udacity.com/course/android-development-for-beginners--ud837)

Answer (score 0):

You can send some information about the list item you clicked on via Intent.putExtra() to the detail activity. For example an id to specify the list item. You can send a lot of things via Intent but I prefer to send few information via Intent. If you want to work with the id for example you can save the rest of the information in a database and then get it from the id.

Long story short, when you got the required information you can then set the content or edit the content in code to fit the selected list item.